# Combining netword3D and mermaid in Rmarkdown messes up rendering

Tags: r, r-markdown, htmlwidgets, networkd3, diagrammer

I would like to include two `htmlwidgets` in the same Rmarkdown document - a `mermaid` flowchart from the `DiagrammeR` package and a `network3D` graph. If I include both in my document then none of them renders but if I only include one of them then it will be rendered.

Here's a minimal example in Rmarkdown that shows the problem

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Me"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## The grViz always works

```{r dia1, echo=FALSE}
library(DiagrammeR)
grViz("
  digraph {
    layout = twopi
    A -> {B C D}
  }")
```

# From here onwards I can only include one of the two graphs 

```{r}
mermaid("
graph LR
    A-->B
")
```

# Plot

```{r}
library(networkD3)
Source <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D")
Target <- c("B", "C", "D", "J", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I")
NetworkData <- data.frame(Source, Target)

# Create graph
simpleNetwork(NetworkData)
```
````

If I add multiple `DiagrammeR` graphs based on `grViz` then all is fine and dandy. Also if I leave out the `mermaid` plot then I'll see the remaining two. Are they not supposed to play together nicely? I've tried to swap the ordering of the `library` calls to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`networkD3` was updated to D3v4 in [version 0.3](https://github.com/christophergandrud/networkD3/blob/master/NEWS.md#03) in. Feb. 2017, which is not compatible with v3 versions of D3, which is what `DiagrammeR` appears to use. `htmlwidgets`, which is the underlying package that drives `networkD3` and `DiagrammeR`, only uses the most recent version of a dependency, so htmlwidgets that use conflicting versions of the same library can not both work. Check [here](https://github.com/christophergandrud/networkD3/issues/162) for a starting point of discussion about this problem.

You have a few possible options, though none of them are great...

1. revert `networkD3` to a version < 0.3 so that it also uses D3v3
2. lobby for the [`DiagrammeR` developers](https://github.com/rich-iannone/DiagrammeR) to upgrade to D3v4
3. lobby for the [htmlwidgets` developers](https://github.com/ramnathv/htmlwidgets) to come up with a robust way of dealing with conflicting JavaScript dependencies

Comment: Yup. That is exactly it. I've filed an [issue with the DiagrammeR](https://github.com/rich-iannone/DiagrammeR/issues/232) developers and we will see how that pans out. Thanks!